# Removing little move up effect on hover

Tags: css

I have an e-commerce hosted in one of that "ready to sell" online stores, where it doesn't allow me to edit the CSS files but allow me to add css properties via admin panel. The problem that I need help is: The main menu of my site has that effect that do a little move up in the item hovered, as you can see in http://soulfighter.lojaintegrada.com.br/. And I really don't know what to add in my CSS to remove this effect. If i could access the CSS file, I believe I would find this effect and remove, but since i have no access to IT, I really don't know what to add to my css to remove that.

Comment: the url you posted is not found..

Comment: Corrected. Sorry and thanks, Gaby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to learn how to use some developer tools. For example, I am using Chrome.. if I right click and inspect the element, I can then view the styles applied to it, which immediately showed me this:

```
.menu.superior .nivel-um > li:hover {
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Remove or override this and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that in Firebug! Set to margin-top to 0 and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As it is a hover state, it may not be readily apparent. Inspectors usually have options to toggle on or off different states such as hover or focus, allowing you to see those styles